# Does WCF convert parallel calls from the same client (using different threads) to be in serial?

Tags: c#, wcf, multithreading

I have self hosted net tcp WCF service that exposes two methods and the service is not thread safe and it is (PerSession) .

I found that my colleague developer who is using the service, accesses the same service object from different threads, and till now it works fine.

So I am asking if you have parallel call from the same client then the service will serial? or I am wrong? and is that good to access wcf service object from different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "per session" is the ["instance context mode"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) - this just guarantees to give you the same service-side object (implementing the service) for the duration of the session. I believe you should look at the ["concurrency mode"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx). If this is "single" then the calls are synchronized (serial) - but that isn't the only setting; "multiple" and "re-entrant" would allow multiple threads into the service at once.

Comment: okay, I am asking about the different calls from the same client, and what is the default concurrency mode because I did not mention it on the service

Comment: The default is single, so yes they would be serial. Note that this is used *in combination* with the instance context mode - so only calls on the same session will be serialized (but two different sessions with separate svc objects can run in parallel).

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 8 of Juval Lowy's "[Programming WCF Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521301/)" contains pretty much everything you might possibly need to know about concurrency with WCF.  It's the unofficial "bible" of WCF.  I strongly suggest checking it out.